# Fail2ban Error on start

Tags: logging, fail2ban

Recently, I have tried restarting `Fail2ban` and I have received an error, making it impossible to start... The full error I received from `systemctl status fail2ban` is as follows:

```
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 03 18:27:02 nerdofcode.com systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The full output of `cat /var/log/fail2ban.log` is:

```
2018-01-03 18:06:28,337 fail2ban.server         [25119]: INFO    
Exiting Fail2ban
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions towards this issue.

Comment: is that error line from `/var/log/fail2ban.log`?

Comment: The error is provided from `systemctl status fail2ban`

Comment: Then check `/var/log/fail2ban.log`. Hopefully it will give you a detailed trace of the reason of failure.

Comment: [This may help](http://www.sebdangerfield.me.uk/2011/08/debugging-fail2ban-not-starting/)

Comment: This has temporarily fixed the issue.  But, I'm looking for a long term fix

Comment: That's not a solution, it will help you to identify errors on your config, so you can fix them and then restart the service properly.

Answer (score 14):

There is a good chance that the error has been logged to `/var/log/fail2ban.log` however you can also see what the problem is by running `fail2ban-client -x start` and you will get something descriptive.

In my case it was an exim rejectlog that did not yet exist.

Credit to @bistoco's comment on the question.

Comment: `fail2ban-client -x start` is very helpful! In my case there was nothing in `/var/log/fail2ban.log`

Answer (score 0):

The error was not logged in `/var/log/fail2ban.log` as suggested elsewhere. 
You better stop beforehand the `fail2ban` process. On `systemd` you do a :

```
sudo /usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop
```

For my case it wasn't even running so after that I manually started `fail2ban` and it finally gave me the error:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop
RROR  Failed to access socket path: /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock. Is fail2ban running?
$ sudo /usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start
ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/apache2/*error.log
ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for apache-shellshock jail
```

I went on a corrected the `apache-shellshock` instructions in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` and restarted `fail2ban` and it worked.